# How Numpy two-dimensional array (or pandas DataFrame)take intersection when there is a column has same value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

Assume I have two Numpy two-dimensional-array:

```
A = ('2010-01-04', 8019.0)
    ('2010-01-05', 8046.0)
    ('2010-01-06', 8028.0)
    ...
```

A's columns is 'time' and 'value'

```
B = ('2010-01-03', 3073.0)
    ('2010-01-04', 3068.0)
    ('2010-01-05', 3068.0) 
    ...
```

B's columns is also 'time' and 'value'.
Now I want to select A's and B's rows when A['time'] = B['time'].That is

```
A1 = ('2010-01-04', 8019.0)
     ('2010-01-05', 8046.0)
     ...
B1 = ('2010-01-04', 3068.0)
     ('2010-01-05', 3068.0) 
     ...
```

Is there a efficient way to do that? 
I have tried to pick the intersection of A['time'] and B['time'],and use np.where to select the rows:

```
time_A = np.array(A['time'])
time_B = np.array(B['time'])
time_inter = np.intersect1d(time_A,time_B)
index_A = np.where(time_A == time_inter)
A1 = A[index_A]
```

And about pandas DataFrame,I use the same way to finish the work.Is there a better way?At least do not 'pick up' the 'time' column,get A1 and B1 directly?

Comment: Sorry are you just asking for the intersection like an `inner` `merge`? so `A.merge(B, on='time')`? or `A[A['time'].isin(B['time'])]`?

Comment: Thanks.I tried merge and isin, but there is a error <AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'merge'> , <AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'> .Do you get a error two?